# Calling stored procedure with parameter TABLE OF INTEGER parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net, oracle18c

I'm having a hard time with the most compatibility unfriendly database engine ever a.k.a Oracle.

I have this custom type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE INTEGERS_ARRAY AS TABLE OF INTEGER;
```

And this simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE_MAHMOUD(
    holy_array              IN INTEGERS_ARRAY,
    some_kind_of_number1    IN NUMBER,
    some_kind_of_number2    IN NUMBER,
    query_result            OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
    BEGIN
        OPEN query_result FOR
            SELECT CODE,AIRWAYBILL_DATE,REFERENCE1,REFERENCE2 FROM SHIPMENTS
                ORDER BY AIRWAYBILL_DATE DESC
                FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
    end;
```

This stored procedure is a simplified version of another very complicated one which is also not working. I'm having the same exception on both:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROCEDURE_MAHMOUD'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This is what I tried to do in C#:

```
var result = new List<string>();

using(var con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        command.CommandText = "TEST_PROCEDURE_MAHMOUD";
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Parameters
        var array = new OracleParameter("holy_array", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input);
        array.UdtTypeName = "MY_SCHEMA.INTEGERS_ARRAY";
        array.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        array.Size = 100;
        array.Value = new int[] { 100, 101 };

        var number1 = new OracleParameter("some_kind_of_number1", OracleDbType.Int64, 1, ParameterDirection.Input);
        var number2 = new OracleParameter("some_kind_of_number2", OracleDbType.Int64, 1, ParameterDirection.Input);
        var cursor = new OracleParameter("query_result", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        command.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { array, number1, number2, cursor });

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var awb = reader.GetString(0);
            result.Add(awb);
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

Isn't Oracle supposed to understand the very simple (table of integers) type and accept an array of integer for that type? How can I solve this problem? I have gone through the documentation in the official website, I read code samples on GitHub, I searched a lot and couldn't find any working example only work-around solutions like creating a temp-table which I do not want to do.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the Entity Framework Core tag is because I tried to do this with EF Core first but it didn't work, I switched to ADO.NET, thinking it might be EF Core's issue. But it turns out that EF Core is too good to let me down like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Entity framework core still doesn't support Oracle databases fully, one of the limitations are the custom types:

> Limitations The dedicated team has successfully implemented most
> features support the Entity Framework functionality as much as
> possible for the Oracle Server, but there are some limitations which
> cannot be overcome.
>
> Oracle doesn't have its equivalents for the SQL Server OUTER APPLY and
> CROSS APPLY constructions. User-defined types, including Oracle
> objects, array types and nested tables are not supported.

[Source](https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-oracle)

Comment: It's absolutely unclear, which version this relates to. 2nd? I am now using EfCore 5 and still can't figure out if it's relevant (the given post is of 2018).

Comment: It's always relevant unfortunately, Oracle and .Net just doesn't play nicely together. But when I wrote the question I was using Ef core 2

Comment: I used the following approach which seems to work smoothly: `if (command.Parameters["PATH_LIST"].Value is OracleRefCursor oracleRefCursor)` and if - yes then reading from this cursor... (PATH_LIST is my output cursor parameter)